# Plotting the function using two arguments from the table

Tags: list-manipulation

There is a table expressing the values of T and x, {`T_i,x_i`}. T is the function of x, T(x). The another function F depends on T and x, F(T,x). Using the {`T_i,x_i`} table how the new {`F_i,x_i`} table can be constructed?

Answer (score 1):

```
tab = Table[{T@x, x}, {x, 1, 5}]

{f[##], #2} & @@@ tab
```

> ```
> {{T[1], 1}, {T[2], 2}, {T[3], 3}, {T[4], 4}, {T[5], 5}}
>
> {{f[T[1], 1], 1}, {f[T[2], 2], 2}, {f[T[3], 3], 3}, {f[T[4], 4], 4}, {f[T[5], 5], 5}}
> ```

Or for in-place modification:

```
tab[[All, 1]] = f @@@ tab;

tab
```

> ```
> {{f[T[1], 1], 1}, {f[T[2], 2], 2}, {f[T[3], 3], 3}, {f[T[4], 4], 4}, {f[T[5], 5], 5}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
f1 = Function[x, x*x] (* example first function *)
t1 = {f1[#], #} & /@ Range[5] (* make an example first table *)
f2 = Function[{x, y}, x + y]  (*example second function *)
Map[{f2 @@ #, #[[2]]} &, t1]  (* make an example second table *)
```